# Problems publishing Office Addin

Tags: app-store, office-addins, custom-functions-excel

Actually we are trying to publish an office addin but the first verification by Microsoft fails and some things I do not understand.

*1) Help URL Property 
Your offer must have the helpURL property set in the custom functions metadata. For more information, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-json. Please add the helpURL property and re-submit your offer.*

Extract of manifest.xml

```
<AllFormFactors>
  <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
    <Script>
      <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url"/>
    </Script>
    <Page>
      <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Page.Url"/>
    </Page>
    <Metadata>
      <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url"/>
    </Metadata>
    <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace"/>
  </ExtensionPoint>
</AllFormFactors>
...
<Resources>
  ...
  <bt:Urls>
    ...
    <bt:Url id="Functions.Script.Url" DefaultValue="https://xxx/functions.js"/>
    <bt:Url id="Functions.Metadata.Url" DefaultValue="https://xxx/functions.json"/>
    <bt:Url id="Functions.Page.Url" DefaultValue="https://xxx/functions.html"/>
    ...
  </bt:Urls>
  ...
</Resources>
```

So what am I doing wrong with that? I checked my json file and think there is missing the helpURL, but the json is generated. How can I set a helURL in the function.ts file? And do I provide a help page for each function with a complete description of the function with its paramaters or is a helpURL to the json file that contains all functions enough?

*2) Your add-in description contains references to "App". Please note that the platform name is "Office and SharePoint Add-ins". Please address this issue and resubmit your offer.*

Where can I change this?

Furthermore there are some other questions, that are more generally:

Our add-in is a solution for customers of our main application to be able to use features of the main application within Excel. So you need the main application (with charges) to have any use of the add-in. That is why there is only a login screen with no possibility to "sign up" for the add-in. You log in with the credentials of your main application.

1) Is it abolutely neccessary to allow people to "sign up" even if they do not have the main application?

2) Do we need to provide "test-accounts" for the add-in for everyone? And than, do we need to provide just one sample to see what the add-in does? As I said, the add-in is just interesting for customers of the main application.

3) Under the point firstRunExperience we get a hint to add one or more lines of describing the funtionality of the add-in to provide a clear value preposition. What do we have to do or where do we have to add these lines? it can not be in the add-in because if I check other add-ins there is no description on the first screen of the add-in itself.

4) The support URL leads to a support page from ourself where you have to authenticate. As it seems, this is not allowed, but customers of our main application have an account for the support page. Do we have to create a separate support page just for the add-in without authentication where you can sen a mail etc.?

5) Additional charge disclosures: As we charge users for the use of our main application (not the add-in(!)) do we have to advertise extra costs for the addin?

Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-json#json-metadata-example) for how to add help url for functions.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful for my custom functions. But does anyone have a hint for me concering the other points?